# How do you make an en dash in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

How do you make an en dash in Google Docs?

Answer (score 6):

In the Special characters dialog, you can type in `dash` in the search box and one of those is an en dash.

If you are using Windows, you can use the numeric keypad to enter an [Alt code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code).
(For en dash: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>)

Alternatively, you can copy and paste one in.

From [Google Docs help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3371015):

> ### Insert special characters
>
> You can add special characters into your documents and presentations,
>   such as arrows, shapes, or accent marks.
>
> 1. Open your document or presentation.
> 2. Click the **Insert** menu.
> 3. Select **Special characters**. You can use the drop-down menus to explore categories of characters, or, if you know the Unicode value
>      for the character you’re looking for, you can enter it into the "Hex
>      input" text field.
> 4. After selecting a character, click the **Insert** button to add it to your document.

Answer (score 3):

*Insert* → **Special characters…**

In the opened window, choose **Punctuation** from the left drop-down list and then **Dash/Connector** from the right drop-down one.

[image]

If you are on Mac, try <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (depending on your keyboard layout, of course).

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OSX (High Sierra), the shortcut is <kbd>option</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>